VS Code GitHub Auth Not Working on Linux due to GNOME Environment OS Keyring Error
I'm trying to login to GitHub on VS Code on Ubuntu, but I'm getting the error:

You're running in a GNOME environment but the OS keyring is not available for encryption. Ensure you have gnome-keyring or another libsecret compatible implementation installed and running.

After waiting for a bit, my GitHub still logs in, however if I open a new VS Code page I have to go through this login process again.
Moreover, the GitHub login popup doesn't appear when I try to sign in with VS Code; instead, I have to sign in with a code, which is frustrating. Not sure if these two things are related or not.
Do you happen to know what I can do such that I can login to GitHub on VS Code without these problems appearing?

Any chance you downloaded vs code as a flatpak?

Did you ever resolve this?

This error in Visual Studio Code occurs because the GNOME keyring, which is used to store credentials securely, is not available or is not running correctly. You can get more context on this known issue at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_troubleshooting-keychain-issues
Anyway, in my case it was from Linux. So, start approaching it as follows until you get it resolved:

code --verbose --vmodule="/components/os_crypt/=1" (This for the diagnosis)

Check if gnome-keyring is installed

sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-keyring


Make sure gnome-keyring is running:

ps aux | grep gnome-keyring

If not running:

gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh,gpg


Check if the libsecret library is installed:

sudo apt install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev


Configure VSCode to use  gnome-keyring:


Once gnome-keyring is installed and running, open VSCode and find the configuration file (settings.json) and add the following configuration to enable GNOME Keychain storage.:
> "security.workspace.trust.enabled": true


Restart VSCode

Hope it helps someone else!
